# select data from previous date but exclude saturday and sunday in sql

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to get the data from the previous day, if it is tuesday then I need the data from Monday and this I´ve done with this statement and it works:

```
Date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
        AND Date < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

But my problem is if it is Monday then I need the data from Friday not from Sunday, how can I do this.  I am using SQL Server 2010.

Thanks,
best regards
mayo

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2010** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - take your pick .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL Server you can use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to return an integer representing the day of week.

By default the start of the week is Sunday which returns `1`, therefore Monday is returns `2`. I say by default because I should draw your attention to the [SET DATEFIRST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) command that can alter the default behaviour if used. Be aware of this although it may not affect your particular situation.

Then a simple case statement to provide the relevant offset from today should give yesterday, or on Monday, will subtract 3 days to give the previous Friday:

```
-- Calculate your FROM date i.e. the previous week day
DECLARE @fromDate DATETIME
DECLARE @toDate DATETIME

SET @fromDate = SELECT DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN datepart(dw,getdate()) = 2 THEN -3 ELSE -1 END, GETDATE()) 

-- To remove the time portion then embed this into your original syntax
SET @fromDate = SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN datepart(dw,getdate()) = 2 THEN -3 ELSE -1 END, GETDATE())), 0)

-- Add one day to @fromDate to get the To Date
SET @toDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @fromDate)

-- Final selection simply becomes
Date >= @fromDate AND Date < @toDate
```